# dist zilla cannot release because of untracked git changes

Tags: git, perl, dist-zilla

I'm using [Dist::Zilla](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Zilla) to release my module, however it is not working. I'm using the [Dist::Zilla::Plugin::Git](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Zilla::Plugin::Git) plugin and whenever I do `dzil release`, it won't let me release my module because it says that I have untracked changes. However, the untracked changes are the new files that Dist::Zilla has created for the release! Here is my config file:

```
name    = My::Module
author  = Name
license = Perl_5
copyright_holder = Name
copyright_year   = 2014

version = 0.001

[NextRelease]
[@Git]

[@Basic]
[PodWeaver]

[TestRelease]
[ConfirmRelease]
[UploadToCPAN]

[AutoPrereqs]
```

Is something in the wrong order here? Or am I supposed to actually commit the created files for release? Because I thought they were supposed to be temporary. Here is the output that I get:

```
[@Git/Check] branch master has some untracked files:
[@Git/Check]    My-Module-0.001.tar.gz
[@Git/Check]    My-Module-0.001/Changes
[@Git/Check]    My-Module-0.001/LICENSE
[@Git/Check]    My-Module-0.001/MANIFEST
[@Git/Check]    My-Module-0.001/META.yml
[@Git/Check]    My-Module-0.001/Makefile.PL
[@Git/Check]    My-Module-0.001/README
[@Git/Check]    My-Module-0.001/dist.ini
[@Git/Check]    My-Module-0.001/lib/My/Module.pm
[@Git/Check] branch master has some untracked files:
[@Git/Check]    My-Module-0.001.tar.gz
[@Git/Check]    My-Module-0.001/Changes
[@Git/Check]    My-Module-0.001/LICENSE
[@Git/Check]    My-Module-0.001/MANIFEST
[@Git/Check]    My-Module-0.001/META.yml
[@Git/Check]    My-Module-0.001/Makefile.PL
[@Git/Check]    My-Module-0.001/README
[@Git/Check]    My-Module-0.001/dist.ini
[@Git/Check]    My-Module-0.001/lib/My/Module.pm at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Moose/Meta/Method/Delegation.pm line 110.
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have a `gitignore` similar to https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dist-Milla/lib/Dist/Milla/Tutorial.pod#Create-a-new-ini-and-edit-configurations in order to ignore `My-Module-xxx` folder content entirely?

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be the right approach.

Comment: Ok, I have added it as an answer to see if that works here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your repo should include a `.gitignore` similar to the one [presented in Dist-Milla](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dist-Milla/lib/Dist/Milla/Tutorial.pod#Create-a-new-ini-and-edit-configurations) in order to ignore the content of the release folder.

```
/My-Module-*
/.build
!META.json
```